# R: Find matching string then copying row

Tags: r, formatting, match, data-management

I have a multi-step problem. First step: match text in one string (df1) from one column to another range of columns (df2). There is no order of which columns match and the match could occur anywhere within the range. Once the match is found, copy the df2 row match into df1. Finally, repeat for the entire column.

```
df1= structure(list(Assay = c("ATG_AR_trans_up","NVS_PXR_cis","BSK_VCAM1_up"), p.value = c(0.01,0.05,0.0001)), .Names = c("Assay", "p.value"),row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame") 

df1
Assay               p.value
ATG_AR_trans_up       0.01
NVS_hPXR              0.065
BSK_VCAM1_up          0.001

df2=structure(list(GeneID = c("AR", "VACM1", "TR", "ER", "PXR"), Assay1= c("ATG_ARE_cis", "BSK_hEDG_VCAM1", "NVS_TR_tran", "ATG_ER_UP", "NVS_PXRE_UP"), Assay2= c("ATG_AR_trans_up", "BSK_BE3K_VCAM1", "NA", "ATG_ERE_cis", "ATG_PXRE_cis"), Assay3= c("NVS_AR_trans", "BSK_VCAM1_UP", "NA", "NVS_ERa_CIS", "NVS_PXR_cis"), Assay4= c("Tox21_AR_ARE","NA", "NA", "Tox21_ERaERb_lig", "NA")),  .Names = c("GeneID", "Assay1", "Assay2", "Assay3", "Assay4"),row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")

df2  
    GeneID             Assay1            Assay 2           Assay3
    AR                 ATG_ARE_cis       NVS_hAR          ATG_AR_trans_up
    VACM1              BSK_hEGF_CAM1     BSK_VCAM1_up      BSK_VCAM1_down
    TR                 NVS_TR_tran       NA                  NA
    ER                 ATG_ER_UP         ATG_ERE_cis     NVS_ERa_CIS     
    PXR                ATG_PXR_down      ATG_PXRE_cis      NVS_hPXR
```

Essentially becomes

```
df
Assay           p.value   GeneID    Assay1       Assay2      Assay3
ATG_AR_trans_up  0.01      AR      ATG_ARE_cis  NVS_hAR      ATG_AR_trans_up
NVS_hPXR         0.065    PXR    ATG_PXR_down   ATG_PXRE_cis NVS_hPXR
BSK_VCAM1_up     0.001    VCAM1  BSK_hEGF_CAM1  BSK_VCAM1_up BSK_VCAM1_down
```

For brevity I shortened the df substantially, but it is around 88 Assays and 4,000 some rows to go through for just one match (there are about 30). So a my initial instinct is to loop, but I was told `grep` might be a helpful package (even though it is not for R 3.2.2). Any help would be appreciated though.

Comment: Your example is too small. Try adding a few more matches to show the desired output.

Comment: ok. I'll try. Let me know if edits are acceptable

Comment: You may edit the question.

Comment: you should also use `dput` to deposit your examples, so people don't have to copy your dfs by hand

Comment: I added the dataframes. Hopefully that makes it easier to understand....although I think I made it more confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since OP was interested in a `grep` solution, another way to do it would be,

```
asDF2 <- apply(df2, 1, function(r) do.call(paste, as.list(r)))

do.call(rbind, lapply(1:nrow(df1), 
                  function(i){
                    matchIX <- grepl(df1$Assay[i], asDF2, ignore.case=T)
                    if(any(matchIX))
                      cbind(df1[i, ], df2[matchIX, ])
                  }))
```

The first line creates a character vector with concatenated row assay names of `df2`. The second line loops through `df1` and finds match in `asDF2` using `grepl`

Or equivalently,

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(1:nrow(df1), 
                  function(i){
                    matchIX <- grepl(df1$Assay[i], 
                                     data.frame(t(df2), stringsAsFactors=F), 
                                     ignore.case=T)
                    if(any(matchIX))
                      cbind(df1[i, ], df2[matchIX, ])
                    } ))
```

Note that above variants, can match multiple rows in `df2` to `df1`.

**NOTE**
To test I added new rows to original data frames as

```
df1 <- rbind(df1, data.frame(Assay="NoMatch", p.value=.2))
df2 <- rbind(df2,
         data.frame(GeneID="My", Assay1="NVS_PXR_cis", Assay2="NA", Assay3="NA", Assay4="NA"))
```

Comment: You're amazing. And it worked 50%. I have to basically run this code twice for two different set of dataframes. First one FINALLY worked, but when I ran the second one I got the error: "Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0 
7 stop(gettextf("arguments imply differing number of rows: %s", 
    paste(unique(nrows), collapse = ", ")), domain = NA)

Comment: 6 data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) 
5 cbind(deparse.level, ...) 
4 cbind(p.MDRatT[i, ], AmigoDEV[grepl(p.MDRatT$Assay[i], data.frame(t(AmigoDEV), 
    stringsAsFactors = F), ignore.case = T), ]) 
3 FUN(X[[i]], ...) 
2 lapply(1:nrow(p.MDRatT), function(i) cbind(p.MDRatT[i, ], AmigoDEV[grepl(p.MDRatT$Assay[i], 
    data.frame(t(AmigoDEV), stringsAsFactors = F), ignore.case = T), 
    ])) 
1 do.call(rbind, lapply(1:nrow(p.MDRatT), function(i) cbind(p.MDRatT[i, 
    ], AmigoDEV[grepl(p.MDRatT$Assay[i], data.frame(t(AmigoDEV), 
    stringsAsFactors = F), ignore.case = T), ]))) " Any ideas?

Comment: I am guessing its because you have some `Assay` in `df1` that have no match in `df2`.

Comment: I hope not. They should all have a match somewhere in the dataframe.

Comment: I updated my post for the no match situation. I think this is what the error message is saying for the 0 (`... differing number of rows: 1, 0 ` ). This may also be due to `grep` not matching for some reason (entry error?). Can you give a better example to test?

Comment: IT WORKED. THANK YOU SO MUCH! I've struggling with this monster for weeks. Much much much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

This can be easily done with reshaping. I put all the assays into all caps because that was messing up the matching.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringi)

df2_ID = df %>% mutate(new_ID = 1:n() )

result = 
  df2_ID %>%
  select(new_ID, Assay1:Assay85) %>%
  gather(assay_number, Assay, Assay1:Assay85) %>%
  mutate(Assay = 
           Assay %>% 
           iconv(to = "ASCII") %>%
           stri_trans_toupper) %>%
  inner_join(df1 %>%
               mutate(Assay = 
                        Assay %>% 
                        iconv(to = "ASCII") %>%
                        stri_trans_toupper)) %>%
  inner_join(df2_ID)
```

Comment: Fantastic. How/ where do I save it?

Comment: I've edited so that the answer gets saved in a dataframe called result.

Comment: Thanks! Still having issues though. I'm only getting 19 of the 46 variables back in the results. Plus I get this warning message: "Warning message:
attributes are not identical across measure variables; they will be dropped" any ideas?

Comment: The warning is nothing to worry about. If the joins work correctly, you should get two messages: Joining by: "Assay", and Joining by: "GeneID" . Which variables are you missing? I'm guessing you might want to change Assay4 to Assay88 (or whatever the name of the last assay column is)?

Comment: Yup, I got the other messages "Joining by: "Assay"
Joining by: c("X", "geneid", "Biology")", and I already had switched Assay for to Assay85, but got the same result. Don't know enough about this type of code to try and tinker with it, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is geneid a true key for the rows in df2? In that case, you only want to be joining by geneid. I've edited the code so that this will be the case.

Comment: Not sure what a true key is, but I tried the edit and got less outputs (13). And the 13 stay even if I use the older code. Not sure why it is picking some but not others.

Comment: 13 rows or 13 columns? If it's 13 rows, then you just don't have a lot of matches.

Comment: 13 rows. There should be matches for all 46 rows in df1, but it isn't picking up all of them. I checked to make sure it wasn't a formatting issue, but I'm not seeing anything

Comment: What's going on here (as in my answer) is that there is something subtle about the elements that are supposed to match that is causing them not to match.  It could be anything from capitalization issues, leading or trailing spaces that you don't know exist, or different data types (some stored as character, other as factor, for example).  But for some reason, the cells that you think should match don't actually match.  To check this, find a match that isn't getting picked up properly, and check whether the relevant entries in df1 and df2 are truly identical with `df1[i,j]==df2[k,l]`

Comment: Agreed with the previous. Other things that could cause issues are "invisible" characters. Converting to ascii can sometimes help.

Comment: Ok. Thanks guys. I'll check through this and get back to you when I get the chance!

Comment: I see that there is a difference in the cells, (I get a FALSE when I check it), but I don't know how to fix it or what is different. Is there a way to see what the differences are so I can try to fix them?

Comment: I added an edit to convert to ASCII. This should get rid of any "invisible" characters

Comment: Same problem. 13 rows. I think the problem is that not all of the Assays have geneids. I put fillers in for the geneids with NA, but still got only 13 rows.

Comment: I've edited to create a new ID column, which should take care of this problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96684/discussion-between-ephackett-and-bramtayl).

Answer (score 1):

Since you're new to R, I think you are right that the most intuitive way to do this is with a for-loop.  This is not the most concise or most efficient way to do this, but it should be clear what's going on.

```
# Creating example data
df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(data=c("aa", "bb", "ee", .9, .5, .7), nrow=3))
names(df1) <- c("assay", "p")

df2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(data=c("G1", "G2", "aa", "dd", "bb", "ee", "cc", "ff"), nrow=2))
names(df2) <- c("GeneID", "assay1", "assay2", "assay3")

# Building a dataframe to store output

df3 <- as.data.frame(matrix(data=NA, nrow=dim(df1)[1], ncol=dim(df2)[2]))
names(df3) <- names(df2)

# Populating dataframe with output
for(i in 1:dim(df1)[1]){
  index <- which(df2==as.character(df1$assay[i]), arr.ind = TRUE)[1]
  for(j in 1:dim(df3)[2]){
  df3[i,j] <- as.character(df2[index,j])
  }
}

df <- cbind(df1, df3)
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, took me a little while to run the code but I got it!!

Comment: WAIT. It appeared to me working, but it isn't finding all the matches.Any ideas what might be off?

Comment: this depends on the full structure of your dataframe.  You might try replacing the which statement in the for loop with `which((as.character(df2)==as.character(df1$assay[i]), arr.ind = TRUE)[1]`

Comment: I get an error with the syntax and can't figure out how to fix it: "Error: unexpected ',' in:
"for(i in 1:dim(df1)[1]){
    index <- which((as.character(df2)==as.character(df1$assay[i])," Even when fixed "which(as.character(df2)==as.character(df1$assay[i]), arr.ind = TRUE)[1]" still no good on improving match

Answer (score 0):

***Edit after clarification from user***:

I just created a triple for loop to check your values. Basically what it does is it looks for a match. It does this by looping through all columns and all the values from that column.

However my code is not perfect yet (also a beginner in R) and I just wanted to post it so that maybe we can work something out together :).

So I first convert your data to a data.frame. After that I create an empty output which I later fill per match found.

The improvements in this method would be that with this solution the function append will also append the column names which will result in multiple useless column names.

```
df3 <- as.data.frame(df1)
df4 <- as.data.frame(df2)
output <- data.frame()



for(j in 1:nrow(df3)) {
    match <- FALSE
    for(i in 2:(ncol(df4))) {
        for(p in 1:nrow(df4)) {
            if((df3[j, 1] == df4[p, i]) && (match == FALSE)) {
                output <- append(output, c(df3[j, ], df4[j, ]))
                match <- TRUE
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to add the conditions of matching too. Probably came from the poor way I asked the question. I tried to add the dataframes to make it easier. Is the question still framed poorly? I think I made it worse.

Comment: @ephackett, I think your edits are pretty clear; the DEFINITELY did not make it worse.

Comment: Thanks for adding the information! The part that is not clear in the question is what the condition is for rows to find their match. 

In your first two output rows I notice a match in 'Assay' and 'Assay3'. But in your third row I notice a match in 'Assay' and 'Assay2'.

So should it just find a match in any of the three 'assays' of the second dataframe?

Comment: Yup. There is no specific order of which columns match. I just need to find a match in any of the assay columns (there are actually 88, but for ease of example I thought 3/4 would suffice).

Comment: That's def something you should have mentioned haha. I was thinking about making a for loop but if you have 88 columns then making 88 'if else' statements would be a very bad way of coding.

Comment: Yea, if would be a lot 'if then' statements since the 88 has to be multiplied by the number of rows in df1. Any other suggestions/ tips would be appreciated though.

Comment: I have added a suggestion. It's not perfect yet but maybe we can try and figure it out together :).

Comment: Sounds good. I'll starting hammering through it and we can see what it comes up with

Comment: The only thing that I can't figure out is how I filter the duplicate column names. You can see the output by going: data.frame(output)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96580/discussion-between-ephackett-and-mick).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, you don't have any repeated entry corresponding to the entry in df1. Following is the solution for your problem:

```
assay <-as.matrix(df1[,1])
m1 <- as.numeric(sapply(assay, function(x){grep(x,df2[,2], ignore.case = T)}, simplify = FALSE))
m2 <- as.numeric(sapply(assay, function(x){grep(x,df2[,3], ignore.case = T)}, simplify = FALSE))
m3 <- as.numeric(sapply(assay, function(x){grep(x,df2[,4], ignore.case = T)}, simplify = FALSE))
m4 <- as.numeric(sapply(assay, function(x){grep(x,df2[,5], ignore.case = T)}, simplify = FALSE))

m1[is.na(m1)] <- 0
m2[is.na(m2)] <- 0
m3[is.na(m3)] <- 0
m4[is.na(m4)] <- 0

m0 <- (m1+m2+m3+m4)
df <- NULL
for(i in 1:nrow(df1){
  df3 = cbind(df1[i,],df2[m0[i],])
  df = rbind(df,df3)
}
```

**Edit: Generalization**

Since you have more than 80 rows, you can generalize it as under:

```
assay <-as.matrix(df1[,1])

# Storing Assay column in a list
m <- vector('list',ncol(df2[, 2:ncol(df2)]))
for(i in 1:length(m)){
  m[[i]] <- as.numeric(sapply(assay, function(x){grep(x,df2[,(i+1)], ignore.case = T)}, simplify = FALSE))

}
# Getting row subscript for df2
m1 <- as.data.frame(m)
m1[is.na(m1)] <- 0
m2 <- rowSums(m1)

df <- NULL
for(i in 1:nrow(df1)){
  df3 = cbind(df1[i,],df2[m2[i],])
  df = rbind(df,df3)
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! I unfortunately get the error:

Comment: " Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0 
4 stop(gettextf("arguments imply differing number of rows: %s", 
    paste(unique(nrows), collapse = ", ")), domain = NA) 
3 data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) 
2 cbind(deparse.level, ...) 
1 cbind(p.MDRabT[i, ], AmigoDEV[m0[i], ])" df1 is labeled p.MDRabT and df2 is AmigoDEV in the sheet.

Comment: It's working fine on your example data set.
Let me generalize it.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the extra help!

Comment: The new one works without an error, but it doesn't find all the Assays (some are missing in the dataframe). I was having this issue with some of the other code answers listed. The only one that successfully got around this was user2282381's answer